# Blazemeter Chrome Extension - Correlation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, autocorrelation

I have recorded a script, successfully via Blazemeter Chrome Extension. But now, would like to identify the dynamic values to be correlated. Is there a way to view the recorded responses? It becomes very difficult otherwise.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

I don't think BlazeMeter Chrome extension can store the responses, the options are in:

1. You can enable requests recording in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/) and export requests/responses as [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format))
2. You can switch to JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder),  if you add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and configure it like

   [image]

   the `recording.xml` file will contain all request and response data
3. There is an alternative option of recording a JMeter test: BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder, it has nice feature of exporting recorded tests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.